# How can I use the value of a model atributte inside a <img> src?

Tags: html, django, django-models

I am trying to create a project in which a model attribute is used as part of an image name. I have tried many methods and I think I am close to the solution, but I have a problem. This is my code:

```
<img src="{% static 'media/{{model.atributte}}.jpg' %}"  alt="{% static 'media/{{model.atributte}}.jpg' %}"></img>
```

For example: if the value of the attribute is "img" this should result in = static/media/img.jpg
My intention was to use that to set the src path but [this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b97s.jpg) I get in the HTML.

> /static/media/%7B%7Bmodel.atributte%7D%7D.jpg

I appreciate any kind of help or recommendation, as an extra comment, I want to clarify that if I write the value of the attribute in the src it does locate the image, but would always do it for the same model and I have several models. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding the model attribute to the view's context separately? or do you have lots of images to display in your html?

Comment: i have lots of images, at least one per model instance.

Answer (score 2):

If you let Django serve media files during development, and let the webserver (like Apache, Nginx, etc.) serve the media files during production, you can work with the `.url` attribute:

```
<img src="{{ model.atributte.url }}"  alt="{{ model.atributte.url }}">
```

For more information, see the [*serving files uploaded by a user during development* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development).